# How do you see the specific "data in" load for an Azure App Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

My Azure App Service is running a C# MVC application which has been running great for several years. Then last week it started taking up to several minutes between page loads - for pages with no significant database access! I restarted the Azure App Service and the page loads were back to normal, but then it appeared again a day later.
No update has been applied for at least a couple of months, so I am a bit at a loss here.

I am seeing the "data in" graph linked below in the Azure portal, which troubles me a bit since I have no idea why 600 KB is going in every 5 minutes. I haven't been able to figure out how to get details on this data, so does anyone have any idea how to see where this data originates from and possibly what it consist of?

[Azure Data In Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdPli.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per on my understanding, you could leverage [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/) for monitor your web app. For a simple way, you could refer to [Monitor a live Azure web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now#monitor-a-live-azure-web-app) to enable monitoring. Then you could monitor the requests as follows:

[image]

Also, you could leverage [Analytics in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics) to find more details about your clients against the specific requests as follows:

[image]

Comment: Is there a direct route to a web app's raw http request logs that does not involve setting up AppInsights?

Comment: You could enable **Web Server Logging**, for more details you could refer to [How to enable diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log#enablediag) and [How to: Download logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log#download).